# Iterating a HashMap with a condition

Tags: android, data-structures, iterator

First, sorry for my English.

I'm starting with Android and I have a problem with a LinkedList. I want to put a condition inside the iterator, but when the condition is OK, the iterator shows only one map entry (the HashMap have key and value <String, String>, but (and this is curious) when the condition not validate (the system.out.println is outside the if) it's shows 2 values of the HashMap.

Can anybody help me?

Many thanks.

(data is a LinkedList)

```
private void setDataBuscar(LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>> data){

        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();        


        Iterator it = data.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {

            hm = (HashMap) it.next();


            Iterator empleos = hm.entrySet().iterator();
            Map.Entry empleo;

            while (empleos.hasNext()) {
                empleo = (Map.Entry) empleos.next();

                
                String valor = empleo.getValue().toString();
                String llave = empleo.getKey().toString();//-->here llave have value

                
                system.out.println(valor+" "+llave);//--> here shows all dates(TITLE LINK)
                //  of the hasmap, without filter
  
                if(valor.contains(aBuscar)){
                    System.out.println(valor);
                    System.out.println(llave);//--> here dont shows llave ???
                }
                
                        
              }
```

Comment: What do you mean with `but when the condition not validate (the system.out.println is outside the if)`? Do you mean if you remove the `if(valor.contains(aBuscar))` check, then both entries are printed? How is that curious? You want any data printed without any filtering the program does that? Please rewrite your question to clarify your problem.

Comment: Hi Jens ,i'll use a example, may be is better, its dificult to me to explain in english. The hasmap have <String String> by example(car, tires)....many like this, if i try to show only the entries that have "car" , inside th iterator would put a condition if(map.getkey.contains("car"){Toast.make...."key"+map.getkey+" values"+map.getvalue, and it should show "car tire", but only shows "car". If i probe to do without the condition shows all values correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret your comment that you like to loop over the list and print every title-link pair of the currently selected entity where the title contains the word `car` (or in your code `aBuscar`). If this is correct, this is the code to achieve this behavior:

Class that stores single title-link pair:

```
public class TitleLink {

  private String title;
  private String link;

  public TitleLink() {
    this.title = "";
    this.link = "";
  }

  public TitleLink(String title) {
    this.title = title;
    this.link = "";
  }

  public TitleLink(String title, String link) {
    this.title = title;
    this.link = link;
  }

  public boolean titleContains(String title) {
    return this.title.contains(title);
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public String getLink() {
    return link;
  }

  public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "TitleLink {title=" + title + ", link=" + link + "}";
  }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class Test {

  private static String aBuscar = "car";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<TitleLink> example = new LinkedList<>();

    example.add(new TitleLink("carTitle", "firstCarLink"));
    example.add(new TitleLink("carrotTitle", "firstCarrotLink"));
    example.add(new TitleLink("bikeTitle", "bikeCarLink"));
    example.add(new TitleLink("boatTitle", "boatCarLink"));

    example.add(new TitleLink("carTitle", "secondCarLink"));
    example.add(new TitleLink("carrotTitle", "secondCarrotLink"));
    example.add(new TitleLink("bikeTitle", "secondCarLink"));
    example.add(new TitleLink("boatTitle", "secondCarLink"));

    setDataBuscar(example);
  }

  private static void setDataBuscar(List<TitleLink> data) {
    System.out.println("------");
    System.out.println(data); // -> probe ... show whole content of the map
    System.out.println("------");

    for (TitleLink titleLink : data) {
      if (titleLink.titleContains(aBuscar)) {
        System.out.println(titleLink);
      }
    }
  }

  /*
   * This version stores the current title and link in separate variable inside the loop
   * and prints them if the condition is met.
  private static void setDataBuscar(List<TitleLink> data) {
    System.out.println("------");
    System.out.println(data); // -> probe ... show whole content of the map
    System.out.println("------");

    for (TitleLink titleLink : data) {
      String title = titleLink.getTitle();
      String link = titleLink.getLink();

      if (titleLink.titleContains(aBuscar)) {
        System.out.println(title);
        System.out.println(link);
      }
    }
  }*/

}
```

Output:

```
------
// all entries
------
TitleLink {title=carTitle, link=firstCarLink}
TitleLink {title=carrotTitle, link=firstCarrotLink}
TitleLink {title=carTitle, link=secondCarLink}
TitleLink {title=carrotTitle, link=secondCarrotLink}
```

The changes parser class:

```
public class Parser {

    private URL url;
    static TitleLink entry2;

    public Parser(String url) {
        try {
            this.url = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<TitleLink> parse() {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        List<TitleLink> entries = new LinkedList<>();
        TitleLink entry;
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = builder.parse(this.url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("item");
            for (int i=0;i<items.getLength();i++){
                entry = new TitleLink();
                Node item = items.item(i);
                NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
                for (int j=0;j<properties.getLength();j++) {
                    Node property = properties.item(j);
                    String name = property.getNodeName();
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
                      entry.setTitle(property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
                      entry.setTitle(property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                      entries.add(entry);
                      entry = new TitleLink();
                    }
                }
                //entries.add(entry);
                entry2=entry;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return entries;
    }
}
```

I couldn't test the changes of the parser class, because I don't have the webpage that contains the data this class should parse. If you test it and find any bug, you can try to fix them (shouldn't be too hard) or leave a comment.

Comment: first of all thanks for your effort and your time. I tried your classes but I can not implement them because other functions of the application stop working. But me I keep them for a future in an application that starts from the beginning. Just one more thing:) .... if the LinkedList <hashmap <string string> was saving in pairs formed by the key "T" or "L" (final static String DATA_TITLE = "T"; static final String DATA_LINK = "L") and the value, for example: {T, 422884/0 PEONES INDUSTRY OF A ....}, {L, http: //www.webpage.com .......} .

Comment: each step by doing "while empleos.hasNext ()" shows a figure, first one and then a LINK TITLE, so in if it does not, because there is only one thing at a time. If you put counters inside the while'll see. Is there a way that if it meets the condition also save the following? , In two different string variables.

Comment: If you can not devote more time to this learner will understand and will put as a solution validates that you have offered me, if anyone can use it. I'm very tired of trying to work this method.
Thank you very much and greetings.

Comment: I've updated the answer a little bit. I added another version of the `setDataBuscar` method there local variables are used to store the title and the link. Please check if this matches you expectations. And no worries I still want to help you :).

Comment: At last!!!! , I've modificated my main code and use your TitleLink class, and my principal problem has resolve it . Now i have to fight with some little problems , but think i can resolve it, (i hope :) ). Many thanks for your patience and be sure you'll see me again in this forum (jeje).

Answer (score 0):

this is the parser class Tom

public class Parser {

```
private URL url;
static HashMap<String, String> entry2;

public Parser(String url) {
    try {
        this.url = new URL(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>> parse() {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>> entries = new LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> entry;
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document dom = builder.parse(this.url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("item");
        for (int i=0;i<items.getLength();i++){
            entry = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Node item = items.item(i);
            NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
            for (int j=0;j<properties.getLength();j++){
                Node property = properties.item(j);
                String name = property.getNodeName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
                    entry.put(PortadaActivity.DATA_TITLE, property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
                    entry.put(PortadaActivity.DATA_LINK, property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                }
            }
            entries.add(entry);
            entry2=entry;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return entries;
}
```

}